# Nativescript Firebase plugin notification not shown on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm developing an in-house (enterprise) app with Nativescript-Vue and using the [nativescript-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase) to deliver the push notifications. Everything works as expected on Android and iOS 9, but on iOS 10 and above I get the following error:

> Error in application: didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application

The funny thing is that the entitlements file is present and has the 'aps-environment' key. I've tried with both development and production values.
[Entitlements screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELC3R.png)

Of course the app capabilities for push notifications and push notifications in background mode are switched on. [Push notifications screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6Axn.png), [background modes screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iboCC.png).

The provisioning profile was generated after switching the app's push notifications on, and has capabilities and entitlements correctly set. [Provisioning profile screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/do8Pa.png)

I've spent more than thirty hours googling, researching and trying different configurations, but I can't find a way to make it work.

Is there something I'm missing/overlooking?

Comment: Not sure if it's the cause of your problems, but I noticed a typo on the error message. `didFailToRefisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` should probably be `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError`.

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo on the text I typed. Thanks for the remark, I've edited it :)